# how to implement a search bar with fading the existing view when clicked

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

I have implemented search bar in my table view to search for files using `objective-C`. And it is working fine.

I want to implement it in a way that when the search bar is clicked, the screen fades out & only the keyboard & the search bar has user interaction  (like in default phone app or whatsapp or any other ios app).

Can anyone suggest me how that can be done ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What they are using is `UISearchController`, and the dimming effect is the default effect when user activate the search controller, try search on how to implement that

Comment: I am not using that as i need to support iOS 6 .. Any possible way to implement that in UISearchBar ?

Comment: I guess you have to manually create the view and add it to your current vc and bring the UISearchBar to front

Comment: Let me try @Tj3n , but there isn't any property of UISearchbar that allows devs to implement that ?

Comment: I don't think it have, because the UISearchBar is just the search bar, it doesnt have any effect on the controller, you have to implement that in your view controller while inside UISearchBar's delegate method

Comment: Alright .. Thanks .. !!